# Iterate through module in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm facing this problem in AngularJS; I'm using the Drag & Drop from [Github](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested) and I've using the Nested example, but I want to implement the identity types as well, but I can't iterate through the array it gives me cause I really don't know how.

```
list: [
0: {
type: container
allowedTypes: [ ... ]
id: Desayuno
columns: [ ... ]
}
1: {
type: container
allowedTypes: [ ... ]
id: Colación
columns: [ ... ]
}
```

I've just need the allowedTypes values... I've tried this:

```
<ul dnd-list="list"
dnd-allowed-types="(key, allowedTypes) in list">
<h3>{{list.id}}</h3>
```

but it gives me error .-.

Comment: if `dnd-list` expects an array of hashes then your `$scope.list` syntax is wrong; it needs to be `[{type: 'foo'}, {type: 'bar'}, {type: 'blah'}]`

Answer (score 0):

Reading the docs of this lib, there are something wrong in your list. First, it should be an object. Secondely, the key should be a string(not sure, but you can try). Finally, the objets should be nested in the array. So it should be something like this:

```
list: {
'0': [{
        type: container,
        allowedTypes: [ ... ],
        id: Desayuno,
        columns: [ ... ]
}],
'1': [{
        type: container,
        allowedTypes: [ ... ],
        id: Colación,
        columns: [ ... ]
    }]
}
```

Also, you should modify your html to get the right element in the list.